# PHPUnit output with header exceptions (--stderr no result)

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework, testing, phpunit

When testing with zend & phpunit. Header error show on console.
I find the error:

```
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Printer.php:173)
```

I try to debug with the instructions in some topic
[Is there a way test STDERR output in PHPUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348927/is-there-a-way-test-stderr-output-in-phpunit)
and
[PHPUnit output causing Zend_Session exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505130/phpunit-output-causing-zend-session-exceptions).
But when use --stderr option, I can not find some output and report of testcase.
This is the output on the console:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/boingonline/www/testunit# phpunit --stderr
PHPUnit 3.5.15 by Sebastian Bergmann.

root@ubuntu:/home/boingonline/www/testunit#
```

Any ideas for this problem? Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [bug in PHP](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42197). Whenever something is output (even on CLI, that's the problem), you cannot use `header()` calls anymore.

A workaround is to use process isolation for the test with [`@runInSeparateProcess`](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.runInSeparateProcess).

Comment: The link to the PHPUnit documentation is broken: this is a working link for PHPUnit 9.5: [`@runInSeparateProcess`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/annotations.html?highlight=runInSeparateProcess#runinseparateprocess)