# "headers already sent" Error returned during PHPUnit tests

Tags: phpunit, output-buffering

I'm testing a suite of REST web services with PHPUnit. We're using output buffering in order to gzip-encode the responses. When I run a test for the service with PHPUnit, I'm getting the error:

```
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/dotcloud/php-env/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Printer.php:172)
```

It's complaining at the point that my code echo's the output to the browser...

I was able to work around this temporarily by adding an `ob_start()` call at the top of the test class(es), but when I run multiple tests at once, I get this error again.

Any ideas?

Comment: well probably there has been sent out something already before your `echo` but if you don't show any code, we will not be able to help you further than that

Comment: Thanks @bart, but if there were, the error message above would have referenced the place where that "something" was -- not where I'm finally echoing the response to the browser. I'm not echoing anything before the actual response - but PHPUnit is...

Comment: also... added the @outputBuffering annotation, but it's not clear what exactly that does. And it had no effect.

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745080/test-php-headers-with-phpunit?rq=1

Must run tests in isolation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHPUnit output with header exceptions (--stderr no result)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875761/phpunit-output-with-header-exceptions-stderr-no-result)

Comment: Process isolation is just a way around this problem. The problem is caused by something like whitespace after php closing tag ?> or code sends http headers header()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test PHP headers with PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745080/test-php-headers-with-phpunit)

Answer (score 30):

There are several options with different advantages and disadvantages:

1. run the tests in separate processes with `@runInSeparateProcess`, as you already found out. **Good:** better test isolation, **Bad:** worse performance, does not work well with global constants
2. use `--stderr` flag to direct PHPUnit output to STDERR. **Good:** tests work as expected without changes, **Bad:** feels like a dirty workaround, possibly problems with CI tools
3. don't actually send headers. Either replace the classes that use `header()` with stubs or if this is not easily possible or you want to do a full functional test, mock the `header()` function itself. More info on mocking built-in functions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371854/can-i-mock-time-in-phpunit/5337635). **Good:** you can test the contents of the headers as well, your tests do rely less on global state **Bad:** You'll need to write more test code

I'd go for (3) and probably refactor the code as well to have a single class that's responsible for the headers and can be easily mocked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for @fabian-schmengler 3rd option

```php
class Response
    protected function header(string $header) : self
    {
        header($header);
        return $this;
    }
}

class MockResponse extends Response
{
    protected function header(string $header) : self
    {
        echo "header: {$header}\n";
        return $this;
    }
}
```