# Can't execute any test on vagrant box using PHPUnit

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, vagrant, phpunit

I am working for a company. I know how to ran PHPUnit tests on vagrant box. But I don't know why i can't run any test on their vagrant box configured using chef. Whenever i am running `PHPUnit` command, i am getting below error:

```
There was 1 failure:

1) ExampleTest::testBasicExample
A request to [en/contact] failed. Received status code [404].

/..../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:178
/..../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:72
/..../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:53
/..../tests/ExampleTest.php:16

Caused by
ErrorException: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /..../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Printer.php:133) in /..../app/Http/Middleware/SetCookieData.php:17
```

Any help will be very much appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test is running just fine. In your example test, you made a call to `visit('en/contact')`. It attempted to visit that url, but instead of a 200, it got a 404. The display you are seeing is the result of your test attempting to visit that url.

The problem is that your code in `app/Http/Middleware/SetCookieData.php` is attempting to modify the headers (using the `header()` function), but PHPUnit has already written output to STDOUT. So, PHP is throwing an error that you're attempting to modify headers after writing output.

There are a couple answers[1][2][3] for this issue already, but to summarize here:

1. Run PHPUnit with the `--stderr` option (or add `stderr="true"` to your `phpunit.xml`). This way, PHPUnit will write to STDERR, so PHP won't complain about having already written to STDOUT. This is probably the easiest option.
2. Trying using the `@runInSeparateProcess` annotation for your test. Though, you may run into issues because of the complexity of the framework. Additionally, you will probably have many tests that need this annotation, and that will be resource intensive.

   ```
   /**
    * @runInSeparateProcess
    */
   public function testBasicExample()
   {
       // visit('en/contact');
   }
   ```
3. Run PHPUnit with the `--process-isolation` flag (or add `processIsolation="true"` to your `phpunit.xml`). Likely same issues as the `@runInSeparateProcess` annotation.
4. Mock the built-in `header()` function to not actually send headers. Though, this may change how your pages react, so you will probably end up having to write more testing code.

References:

- [1] ["headers already sent" Error returned during PHPUnit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152608/headers-already-sent-error-returned-during-phpunit-tests)
- [2] [Test PHP headers with PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745080/test-php-headers-with-phpunit)
- [3] https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/720

Comment: But the page is right there. I can browse the URL. Why its giving 404 error that's my question.

Comment: Thank you. Will check and let you know.

Comment: Hello, your 3rd option worked for me, but still getting this error:     PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::$name must not be null. Can you help me again?

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes Always willing to help, but you will need to post a new question with the pertinent code.

Comment: my new question link is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278394/phpunit-framework-exception-phpunit-framework-testcasename-must-not-be-null