# PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::$name must not be null

Tags: php, phpunit, vagrant

I am developing on a vagrant box which was custom built to serve the purpose. My PHPUnit version is `5.2.12` and Laravel version is `5.2.22`.

When I am executing `phpunit` command, I get the following errors:

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::$name must not be null.
```

**Code**

Below is my phpunit.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="true"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         stderr="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">app/</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: You probably need to add some code here. phpunit.xml and may be the test itself. `$name` should be assigned in [TestCase constructor](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/5.2.12/src/Framework/TestCase.php#L275) automatically after the class name.

Comment: Can you help me with that? @AlexBlex

Comment: Without code I can only guess. There is no Laravel v 5.2.22 on github https://github.com/laravel/laravel/releases which doesn't help.

Comment: Please go here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases

Comment: I added content of my phpunit.xml

Comment: Of course. Silly me. It [says](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.2.22/composer.json#L77) it works with phpunit `~4.1`, which means <5.0 Try `composer install`. It should downgrade phpunit.

Comment: Well now it installed phpunit 4.8.24. but still getting same error. no change.

Comment: i can see Codeception 2.1.7 also installed previously.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107607/discussion-between-alex-blex-and-william-francis-gomes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So basically the problem was with overwritten `__construct` method:

```
class TestCase extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        //some code which should not be there
    }
}
```

The exception has gone after removing the constructor.

Comment: why do you need to implement the constructor? it is usually better to use `setUp` or `setUpBeforeClass` methods.

Comment: @gontrollez, that's right, there is no need. Sorry if it not clear from the answer. Any better wording is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

by deleting the constructor you just avoiding the error, not solving it. the problem is, you are extending PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase class, which has a constructor with a signature: public function __construct($name = null, array $data = [], $dataName = '').
see the problem? it expects $name, $data and $dataName, and you gave to it nothing!

so, don't remove the constructor, but rewrite it like this:

```
public function __construct($name = null, array $data = [], $dataName = '') {
    parent::__construct($name, $data, $dataName);

    // your constructor code goes here.
}
```

i had the same problem and this solved it perfectly.