# Laravel 4 send headers and PhpUnit testing

Tags: php, http-headers, phpunit, laravel-4

I'm working in a Laravel 4 project having myself forced to include custom headers to the view. It works without problems. But when I try to check my code with PhpUnit the program complains for "Headers already sent..." issue.

So, I though the answer was to call the Response object from the controller (or the newly created view) to proper include the headers in laravel's way but can't find a way to do so. My other workaround was to follow the post: [PHPUnit output with header exceptions (--stderr no result)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875761/phpunit-output-with-header-exceptions-stderr-no-result) and include the `@runInSeparateProcess` PhpUnit command but this throws an exception for duplicating LARAVEL_START constant.

Have you guys found a clean way to achieve this?. I can't go with the stderr redirection fix as I'm trying to run all my test from netbeans IDE and I think this should be a framework's concept I'm missing here.

Thank you all

Comment: First hit for googling "laravel get response object": http://laravel.io/topic/13/laravels-response-class - has a ton of ways to get it, one should match your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This post I've left unattended. @Sven answer reminds me to close it.

In fact, I was looking for a way to "get" the response from the Controller or the View while the correct way is to create a new Response object with the View as a parameter. This fixes Unit Testing issues regarding http headers

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

For laravel 5 you can add this in test:

`use \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;`

Not sure if `WithoutMiddleware` middleware exists in laravel 4.

Comment: Middleware is a L5 feature. Anyway. See my own answer below. Thank you for answering